# Anime where everyone has a crystal inside their body to use magic

Tags: story-identification, anime

I don't remember much about it but the main character was a child (about a few months old) born into a world of magic. To use magic in this world everyone had a crystal inside their body and you had to put your crystal together.

It took most people a few years to do, but since he started at a young age he did it fairly quickly and could use magic as a baby and he also loved to read. He would always go into the library of his house so the parents just decide to put his crib inside the library and when he got older his parents decided to take him to the Capitol to enroll him into a magic school.

Comment: What do you mean by "put your crystal together"?

Comment: I too am curious, like do they push their ribs together or is it in a metaphorical sense like “connecting 2 wires”

Comment: They put the crystal together with their mind sort of since it's not a real crystal it's closer to being their soul

Answer (score 1):

Well I’m about 30% sure, but Knights and magic is an anime where a person dies but is reborn in a magical world and since he was a robot loving otaku in his other life, he wishes to pilot the robots that protect the kingdom from giant monsters and he studies hard as a kid and is ahead of his grade and he liked to read, but he didn’t have his crib in the library, also they use magic by visualizing these intricate lines which could be mistaken as crystals.